# Fine tune a VITS model with the Coqui TTS framework

Tags: python, model, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech, coqui

I am executing the following notebook:

[Google Colab Notebook](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbjctRWVqNlFUbWVFeVoxbnVuSk9UVndfeVJ2QXxBQ3Jtc0tuWTU2MTR0bk5iR3liSDdZcEVtT3I0Wk1Fb3oxQzZfcXZzR19TUHlxX0MwajIyeDR6WlV1LVVWYjVYczF0SzJaUHNITjk0SVd1UHlheHRnNEdmTlh2OEtsdS1PUHhDNFE3RHdPOF95cnljX1dGX0xqRQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fcolab.research.google.com%2Fdrive%2F1Swo0GH_PjjAMqYYV6He9uFaq5TQsJ7ZH%3Fusp%3Dsharing&v=dfmlyXHQOwE)

The notebook is associated with the following YouTube video:

[Updated | Near-Automated Voice Cloning | Whisper STT + Coqui TTS | Fine Tune a VITS Model on Colab](https://youtu.be/dfmlyXHQOwE)

I am able to successfully progress through the notebook until the `trainer.fit()` section. At this point I get the error:

```
OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 12.00 MiB (GPU 0; 14.75 GiB total capacity; 13.41 GiB already allocated; 2.81 MiB free; 13.69 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

Following the advise at [How to avoid "CUDA out of memory" in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129812/how-to-avoid-cuda-out-of-memory-in-pytorch), I added the following code to the Notebook:

1. ```
   import torch
   torch.cuda.empty_cache()
   ```
2. I also reduced my `batch size` all the way down to `1`.
3. I have also added/set the code `%env 'PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:512'` before calling the "trainer.fit()" function.

Finally, it should be noted that I am using a `Colab Pro` account.

If anybody can try out the above notebook and let me know their experience, and also provide any solution to complete the fine tuning and obtain the resultant model.

PS - The following is a summary of my data set:

```
> DataLoader initialization
| > Tokenizer:
    | > add_blank: True
    | > use_eos_bos: False
    | > use_phonemes: True
    | > phonemizer:
        | > phoneme language: en-us
        | > phoneme backend: espeak
| > Number of instances : 131
 | > Preprocessing samples
 | > Max text length: 280
 | > Min text length: 30
 | > Avg text length: 142.8320610687023
 | 
 | > Max audio length: 389781.0
 | > Min audio length: 103209.0
 | > Avg audio length: 225843.31297709924
 | > Num. instances discarded samples: 0
 | > Batch group size: 256.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your sentences are longer, trim them to `=> 2` and `< 10` seconds and try. Usually the VITS PyTorch loader is trying to load all the batch files into ram, then the VITS model too, which results in out of memory.