# CUDA out of memory error when trying to implement Triplet Loss

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, vlad-vector

I'm trying to implement triplet loss for NetVLAD layer, by using 3 different images from my dataloader as follows:

- a - batch with minimal augmentation
- p - same batch with more augmentations
- n - different batch from the same dataloader

However when I try to obtain the VLAD embeddings from my model, I get an out of memory error  after computing the first VLAD embedding. Is there a more efficient way to run this code?

EDIT: Perhaps a better way to load the other batch I need for the negatives?

```
for i, (inputs, poses) in enumerate(train_loader):

    inputs = inputs.to(device)
    # poses = poses.to(device)

    print(inputs.shape)  # anchors
    positives = positive_tfs(inputs)
    positives = positives.to(device)
    print(positives.shape)
    negatives, _ = next(iter(train_loader))  # different random batch thanks to shuffle=True
    negatives = negatives.to(device)
    print(negatives.shape)

    # Zero the parameter gradient
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # FORWARD
    a_vlad, pos_out, ori_out = model(inputs)
    print(a_vlad.shape)
    p_vlad = model(positives, get_pose=False)
    print(p_vlad.shape)
    n_vlad = model(negatives, get_pose=False)
    print(n_vlad.shape)

    # COMPUTE LOSS
    loss = triplet_loss(a_vlad, p_vlad, n_vlad)
    print(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is try to clean the cache. It often frees space and solves the issue. Add this in the beginning of your code.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

If this doesn't work, try reducing the batch-size or the model size.

If none if that works, there is unfortunately nothing much you can do if your GPUs don't have enough memory...

You can have a look there: [How to avoid "CUDA out of memory" in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129812/how-to-avoid-cuda-out-of-memory-in-pytorch)

Comment: Was afraid of that... thanks though!