# Llama-2-7b : CUDA out of memory error while running Llama-2-7b on Google Colab on a T4 instance

Tags: google-colaboratory, llama

i am trying to run Llama-2-7b model on a T4 instance on Google Colab. i am getting a "CUDA out of memory error" while running the code line:

trainer.train().

The GPU memory usage graph on the side shows it at around 6.5/15 GB just before the crash, and at the time of the crash it shoots up to 14.7 GB and then throws the error.
i have tried reducing the batch size to 1, and tried everything else suggested in the following thread.
[How to avoid "CUDA out of memory" in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129812/how-to-avoid-cuda-out-of-memory-in-pytorch).

Can someone point out how i can resolve this problem ? Thanks.
Here is the detailed error message:

> ---

OutOfMemoryError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()

```
  1 # Train model
```

----> 2 trainer.train()

-31 frames-

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py in forward(ctx, A, B, out, bias, quant_state)

```
514         # 1. Dequantize
515         # 2. MatmulnN
```

--> 516         output = torch.nn.functional.linear(A, F.dequantize_4bit(B, quant_state).to(A.dtype).t(), bias)

```
517 
518         # 3. Save state
```

OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 172.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 14.75 GiB of which 72.81 MiB is free. Process 38354 has 14.67 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 13.37 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 303.44 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CON"

Answer (score 1):

After trying out all kinds of suggestions including reducing batch_size to 1 and other suggestions like empty CUDA cache and do garbage collection as found in this link, ([RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374935/how-can-i-fix-this-strange-error-runtimeerror-cuda-error-out-of-memory)), the only thing that worked for me was upgrading to a Colab Pro subscription and using a A100 or V100 GPU with high memory . The particular model i was running ended up using a peak of 22.6 GB (with batch size of 1) on the A100 GPU VRAM

Answer (score 0):

The GPU you were using simply did not have enough RAM to train this model.

When training you need to consider, additional to the model parameters and data, memory that is consumed by the optimiser state and the activations.

You might find this post helpful https://blog.eleuther.ai/transformer-math/